# Selenium selecting a dropdown for options

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying for the past couple of days to select a dropdown and at least print out the options available, but I just cannot get it to work.

I am getting the this error when I run the module.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sel_test_elements2.py", line 20, in 
    print ([o.text for o in select_element.options])
AttributeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute 'options'

Currently my code looks like this.

````
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Define Global Variables
url = "https://games.pcaha.ca/teams/4329"
csv_file = "game_schedule_4329.csv"
games = []

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

# Locate the Sector and create a Select object
select_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".team-filters")
# this will print out strings available for selection on select_element, used in visible text below
print ([o.text for o in select_element.options])```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you face is the fact that this website is using react and doesn't use default Select and Options. They have a custom dropdown implemented, so the way to interact with it is the same as interaction with regular web elements, Select and Options won't work in this case.

I modified your code and it works for me in Chrome:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from time import sleep

# Define Global Variables
url = "https://games.pcaha.ca/teams/4329"
csv_file = "game_schedule_4329.csv"
games = []

# create a new Chrome session
driver = Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

sleep(3) # make sure svgs load before interaction

# Click on arrow down
arrow = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".team-filters svg")[1].click()

# Collect options
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'react-select-2')]")

# Print text from options
print([o.text for o in options])
```

Note: when manually opening the dropdown in your browser and trying to use web inspector, it closes, so in order to get the html inside a dropdown, you can use something like:

```
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.css-kj6f9i-menu")
dropdown_html = dropdown.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

I hope it helped. Good luck!

Comment: This worked, many thanks for the assistance, I will work on the rest of my script now as I will be needing to select one of the dropdown options and then pulling the schedule of the games.

Answer (score 1):

I have used something similar in a small script i have written, may be it can give you an hint on how to go about

**Approach 1** This is to select the last of the options available

Variable `options` in the code below gets be the option available for the dropdown

```
select_datebox = driver.find_element_by_id('jrnyDateSrchTxt') # Drop down selection, you have to change the id appropriately
select_datebox.click()
time.sleep(2)
options = select_datebox.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
options[len(options)-1].click() #selecting the last option
```

**Approach 1** entering the option via a variable

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("jrnyDateSrchTxt")) # Drop down selection, you have to change the id appropriately
time.sleep(1)
select.select_by_value(datadate) # Date selection
time.sleep(2)
```